# Локальные переменные в стеке

Tags: ассемблер, стек

По мере разбора asm кода не могу понять одну вещь, связанную со стеком.

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 48h
push    ebx
push    esi
push    edi
lea     eax, [ebp+var_4]
push    eax
push    offset aD       ; "%d"
call    sub_CAA738
add     esp, 8
```

Почему адресом локальной переменной будет являться `[ebp+var_4]`, т.е. к адресу стека прибавляют размер указателя, разве в данном случае в регистре назначения не будет храниться какой-то мусор ниже адреса стека ведь мы прибавляем ко дну стека?
Хотелось бы узнать в любом случае почему это так происходит, в гугле к сожалению не нашел описания той части этого механизма, которая меня интересует.

Comment: Будет храниться мусор, это просто выделение памяти в стеке под локальные переменные без их инициализации. Аналогично, если на Си писать: если вы объявите локальные переменные, но не инициализируете - в них будет храниться мусор.

Comment: И, кстати, в выражении `[ebp+var_4]` к базе фрейма не прибавляется размер указателя, а вычитается смещение от базы до локальной переменной. Все константы `var_` в IDA (для ebp-фреймов)- отрицательные константы, а все `arg_` - наоборот, положительные. И на всякий случай: команда `lea` загружает в регистр назначения не значение второго операнда, а его адрес. В данном случае это будет сумма (разность) `ebp+var_4`. Но я всё же надеюсь, что вы не путаете `lea` с `mov`.

Answer (score 1):

Будет храниться мусор, это просто выделение памяти в стеке под локальные переменные без их инициализации. Аналогично, если на Си писать: если вы объявите локальные переменные, но не инициализируете - в них будет храниться мусор.

Спасибо @insolor за ответ, стало понятно